# Wrapping js code with mobile wrapper: what to use?

Tags: javascript, flutter, react-native, native

I have a js game (pixi.js) which I want to publish in Google Play.

**I wonder how to do it? Which technology can be used to wrap the javascript code into a mobile application?**

I checked description of Flutter and React Native, but they seem to be not relevant to what I need.

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/

Comment: @Konrad Cordova seems to be an outdated option =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

[This](https://medium.com/@danielbyron/porting-an-html-pixijs-game-to-android-18422ea2e9a9) guide on Medium by *Daniel Byron* seems to cover all steps for converting your Pixijs game to an android app.

You'd obviously need to setup `Android Studio` (also included in this guide), apart from that it uses `Webpack` and `Java`

Note: *"This assumes you have your game as a standalone build (built using something like webpack) and doesn’t rely on any external dependencies or links."* quoting from the guide itself.

**Option 2**

Simply create a `PWA` for your HTML app which can be published to google play as well as can be downloaded as web app.

Refer these for creating a PWA from your HTML project: [A Guide on Devto](https://dev.to/developertharun/convert-any-website-into-a-pwa-in-just-3-simple-steps-35pp) another one on [Medium](https://medium.com/notonlycss/turn-your-website-into-a-pwa-6aaecb95f8b9) and this one at [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-a-pwa-from-scratch-with-html-css-and-javascript/)

Comment: Thnx a lot! Especially for reminding me about the PWA option!

Comment: I'm glad it worked, probably close the question for the community because there seems to be no similar question available on the web and this might be a common doubt for developers using Pixi.js